# scikit-learn: How to use the fitted probability model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I have used scikit-learn's `Gaussian mixture models`(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) to fit my data, now I want to use the model, How can I do it? Specifically:

1. How can I plot the probability density distribution?
2. How can I calculate the mean square error of the fitting model?

Here is the code you may need:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from sklearn import mixture
import matplotlib as mpl

from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
%matplotlib inline

n_samples = 300

# generate random sample, two components
np.random.seed(0)
shifted_gaussian = np.random.randn(n_samples, 2) + np.array([20, 5])
sample= shifted_gaussian 

# fit a Gaussian Mixture Model with two components
clf = mixture.GMM(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(sample)

# plot sample scatter
plt.scatter(sample[:, 0], sample[:, 1])

# 1. Plot the probobility density distribution
# 2. Calculate the mean square error of the fitting model
```

UPDATE:
I can plot the distribution by:

```
x = np.linspace(-20.0, 30.0)
y = np.linspace(-20.0, 40.0)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
Z = -clf.score_samples(XX)[0]
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)

CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1.0, vmax=1000.0),
                 levels=np.logspace(0, 3, 10))
CB = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.8, extend='both')
```

But isn't it quite strange? Is there better way do to it? Can I plot something like this?
[image]

Comment: Why you think the result is not right? See the modified plot below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the result is reasonable, if you adjust the xlim and ylim a little bit:

```
# plot sample scatter
plt.scatter(sample[:, 0], sample[:, 1], marker='+', alpha=0.5)

# 1. Plot the probobility density distribution
# 2. Calculate the mean square error of the fitting model
x = np.linspace(-20.0, 30.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-20.0, 40.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
Z = -clf.score_samples(XX)[0]
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)

CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1.0, vmax=10.0),
                 levels=np.logspace(0, 1, 10))
CB = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.8, extend='both')
plt.xlim((10,30))
plt.ylim((-5, 15))
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I just mean that can I get rid of the setting of X, and Y, and let `matplotlib` to handle it? It's really tiring to plot this way.

Comment: Is there anything like `plt.density(Z)`? I just wan to plot simpler.

Comment: I guess `plt.imshow(Z, cmap=cm.gray)` will sort of do it? But them you have to get the axis aligned (x,y are going to be off-scale). Might just well stay with `contour`.

Comment: And it is a expectation-maximization fitting method, the goodness of fit is measured by [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), loglikelihood, etc. Access those using `clf.bic(sample)``clf.aic(sample)`

Comment: I may not be clear enough. I'm not saying the problem of the method of fitting. It's just there're `too much code` to `plot a probability density function`. I just want to know how can I plot the density function easily.

Comment: @cqcn1991 With matplotlib you usually need to code *that much* (I don't see 10 lines like too much). Why don't you just create a function (`def density(...): ...`) with all that code inside? Which is the problem with doing that?